# show the month in mothcalander control in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, listview, monthcalendar

i have a listview Containing the names of months. i have a monthcalender control. i want to know if this is possible wthen i click a month name in  the listview  .it shows the month name in monthcalander control ?

```
Dim arr(3) As String
    Dim itm As ListViewItem
    arr(0) = "2015"
    arr(1) = "Jan"
    itm = New ListViewItem(arr)
    ListView1.Items.Add(itm)
    arr(0) = "2015"
    arr(1) = "feb"
    itm = New ListViewItem(arr)
    ListView1.Items.Add(itm)
    arr(0) = "2015"
    arr(1) = "Mar"
    itm = New ListViewItem(arr)
    ListView1.Items.Add(itm)
    arr(0) = "2015"
    arr(1) = "Apr"
    itm = New ListViewItem(arr)
    ListView1.Items.Add(itm)
```

in this part i get the month name in textbox. iwant to show the month name in month calander control

```
  Private Sub ListView1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.Click
    Dim tt As String
    Dim tt1 As String
    tt = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(1).Text
    tt1 = ListView1.SelectedItems.Item(0).SubItems(0).Text
    TextBox1.Text = tt.ToString & vbCr & tt1
  End Sub
```

Any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the Code  to the Listview click

```
Dim sr As New SelectionRange()
sr.Start = DateTime.Parse(Me.TextBox1.Text)
Me.MonthCalendar1.SelectionRange = sr
```